# C To Query DropBox

Tags: c, dropbox-api

I am attempting to use the C API to query dropbox, but I am getting an error of:

> Account info error (400): invalid_request

I have looked at my developer Dropbox settings and verified that I populated the variables `c_key, c_secret` with the values from App Key & App Secret.

What should I change in my code so this executes succesfully?

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

int err;
void* output;
char *c_key    = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
char *c_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";   
char *t_key    = NULL; 
char *t_secret = NULL; 

drbInit();
drbClient* cli = drbCreateClient(c_key, c_secret, t_key, t_secret);
drbSetDefault(cli, DRBOPT_ROOT, DRBVAL_ROOT_AUTO, DRBOPT_END);
output = NULL;
err = drbGetAccountInfo(cli, &output, DRBOPT_END);
if (err != DRBERR_OK) {
    printf("Account info error (%d): %s\n", err, (char*)output);
    free(output);
} else {
    drbAccountInfo* info = (drbAccountInfo*)output;
    displayAccountInfo(info);
    drbDestroyAccountInfo(info);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are at least two issues here:

1. You're not supplying an access token (which would be in `t_key` and
   `t_secret` in this code), so you can't make an authenticated API
   call, such as to retrieved account information.
2. [The library you're using](https://github.com/Dwii/Dropbox-C) uses Dropbox API v1, which has been
   [retired](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/09/api-v1-shutdown-details/), so this would still fail even with a valid access
   token. You should use [Dropbox API v2](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/09/api-v1-shutdown-details/) instead. Dropbox doesn't
   offer an official SDK for using Dropbox API v2 from C, from you can
   call [the HTTPS endpoints](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) directly, or use a third party library
   that does so.

Comment: Thanks so much! That really really helps! I need to find a 3rd party library that will call the HTTPS endpoints, right?

Comment: You don't _need_ to use a third party library, but it would probably be easier than implementing it yourself.